# Disappearing border lines in table

Tags: tables, color, arrays, overleaf

I am trying to draw a table like below. The preview in overleaf is perfect as shown below.

[image]

However, after I render in texstudio using pdflatex, the cell border lines are sporadically missing like below.

[image]

Below is the MWE to produce above table:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hpt]
\newcommand\x{\times}  % just for easy cross
\def\cx{\cellcolor{cyan!20}}
\def\cb{\cellcolor{yellow!20}}
\def\cg{\cellcolor{gray!20}}
\centering
    $$
    \begin{array}[!hpt]{ |>{\columncolor{gray!20}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|  } \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!20} 
        {j \backslash i} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\ 
        \hline
        y_1 & {\cg} R_{11} & \cb R_{12} & \cb R_{13} & \cb R_{14} & \cb R_{15} & \cb R_{16} \\ \hline
        y_2 & {\cx} R_{21} & \cg R_{22} & \cb R_{23} & \cb R_{24} & \cb R_{25} & \cb R_{26} \\ \hline
        y_3 & {\cx} R_{31} & {\cx} R_{32} & \cg R_{33} & \cb R_{34} & \cb R_{35} & \cb R_{36} \\ \hline
        y_4 & {\cx} R_{41} & {\cx} R_{42} & {\cx} R_{43} & \cg R_{44} & \cb R_{45} & \cb R_{46} \\ \hline
        y_5 & {\cx} R_{51} & {\cx} R_{52} & {\cx} R_{53} & {\cx} R_{54} & \cg R_{55} & \cb R_{56} \\ \hline
        y_6 & {\cx} R_{61} & {\cx} R_{62} & {\cx} R_{63} & {\cx} R_{64} & {\cx} R_{65} & \cg R_{66} \\ \hline
    \end{array}
    $$
\caption{Sample Matrix}  \label{tab:3}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

When I copy the above code in texstudio and run, I get the missing border lines as I just explained but same code creates perfect table in overleaf. What could be going wrong?

Comment: This might be connected with your macros. Some may glob whitespaces. Try your array with `\cx{}`, `\cg{}` and `\cb{}` in overleaf and TeXstudio.

Comment: This is a known viewer issue with colored cells. Just search the site for colored table cells overlapping.

Comment: even after \cg{} kind of modification, same issue exists

Comment: I don't think it's a real problem, but rather a viewer issue.